# How i calculate max selects of data from 2 arrays before reach cap

Tags: arrays, algorithm

i have 2 arrays (stacks):
9 index is top of stack

[5,1,1,-,-,-]
[5,6,5,1,1,1]

I can get only 0 index from arrays and remove it from array
How calculate max selects before sum of elements reach <=20?
Arrays can be very large

Answer For example:
max is 6 (5+6+5+1+1+1) - full sum of 2 array

1. get 5 from 2 array (5 =5)
2. get 6 from 2 array(5+6 =11)
3. get 5 from 2 array(5+6+5 =16)
4. get 1 from 2 array(5+6+5 +1 =17)
5. get 1 from 2 array(5+6+5 +1+1 =18)
6. get 1 from 2 array(5+6+5 +1+1+1 =19)
7. get 5 from 1 array(5+6+5 +1+1+1 +5 =24) we don get this try because 24>20

Other variants (5):

1. get 5 from 1 array (5 =5)
2. get 1 from 1 array(5+1 =6)
3. get 1 from 1 array(5+1+1 =7)
4. get 5 from 2 array(5+1+1 +5 =12)
5. get 6 from 2 array(5+1+1 +5+6 =18)
   6.get 5 from 2 array(5+1+1 +5+6+5 =23)we don get this try because 23>20

Comment: Can you clarify the problem you are facing? "How calculate max selects" - what does that mean?

Comment: I cannot define common algorithm for different input arrays

Comment: What does the 9 in `[two stacks]: 9 index is top of stack` stand for?

Comment: This would be more clear if you didn't use the word _array_ at all. It would be better you just used the word **stack**.  For example when you say _"I can get only 0 index from arrays and remove it from array"_  You're just describing the **pop** operation of a stack.  It sounds like you're asking "how can I pop elements from a stack until their sum reaches 20".  I don't get what the second stack is for.  It seems like you just take elements from the second stack when the first stack is empty.

Comment: @Wyck you, all understand. Arrays in this case is stacks. You can pop any from 2 stack. Need calculate possible max pops before reach 20. All element of stack I know, but can only pop ( index 0 of array)

Comment: I'm curious to know if this was an interview question?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a cumulative sum array for both arrays. For example, the cumulative sum for `[5,1,1,-,-,-]` would be `[5,6,7,-,-,-]`, and for `[5,6,5,1,1,1]` it would be `[5,11,16,17,18,19]`.
2. Use the [two pointer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-pointers-technique/) approach to find the sum which is closest to the target sum (which is `20` in your case)

If the arrays are guaranteed to have non-negative elements, this approach would have an `O(1)` complexity.

Comment: (Or, for target *t* and *elements greater than zero*, O(t), regardless of *n* = elements in both stacks.)